# Drupal: Is there a "Large Print" display option?

Tags: drupal, accessibility, bootstrap-5

I am working on a Drupal 10 site with a Bootstrap 5 (Barrio) custom theme. I have some older followers who would find it easier to view the site if the type was larger.  I want to provide a large-print option for them.  Is there a way (such as a user-selectable option) to accomplish this through the theme?

It looks as if "Userway" is an option, but it is expensive and offers several features that I don't need.

Comment: Can they not just zoom in their browser? Seems overkill to create this if there is already the ability built into every browser on the market.

Comment: Thanks to Eric and Slugolicious.  I know that the browser function exists, but I wanted to offer an on-screen option that would be more intuitive for users.  I am going to try the solution suggested by California.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this posted on the [drupal group](https://groups.drupal.org/node/536894) too with similar answers/comments. The user can use the browser built-in zooming feature (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>).

I would strongly **discourage** the use of userway or any other overlay plugin. While some of the overlay plugins have a few features that might be helpful to users, in general, the overlays cause additional accessibility issues.

However, all that being said, you can do a simple font size increase if you want to implement your own. Take a look at the [State of Califoria website](https://www.ca.gov/). In the upper right they have a "Settings" button.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

and that will reveal a few accessibility features, one of which is increase/decrease font.

[image]

All they do is add 0.1 to the 'rem' font size for the entire page. The main <html> element has

```
<html class="js flexbox" style="height: 100%; font-size: 1rem;" lang="en">
```

And when you click on the "increase font size" button, they just

```
function() {
  p = g(p += .1)
}
```

and if you have the code inspector open, you'll see the main <html> change to

```
<html class="js flexbox" style="height: 100%; font-size: 1.1rem;" lang="en">
```

`font-size` went from "1rem" to "1.1rem".